# How to correctly pass Activity to AccountManager in background thread?

Tags: android, android-activity, accountmanager

Question to **ANDROID developers** only:

I'm looking for help with understanding of `AccountManager` class (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html).

In docs there is a note: *Requests which may block, including `getResult()`, must never be called on the application's main event thread.*
Some of these requests require `Activity` to start another `intent` if needed.

I guess in `getResult()` a new `intent` could be started as sub-activity to the `activity` passed to the request, but this code is executed on **background thread** and activity passed to request could be already destroyed due to different reasons.

When I use `getResult()` on **background thread**, how can I be sure that `Activity` is **not destroyed** (e.g. due to screen rotation)?

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: I did. What does not work in your code?

Comment: @igor-zubchenok `Activity` is always destroyed on screen rotation.

Comment: @JPVentura That's why I asked this question 5 years ago. If activity is destroyed, but it has a background thread.